# Yara command line throws non-ascii character error

Tags: command-line, ascii, yara

I want to test Yara but when I try the following rule I get a non-ascii character error:

```
rule basetest{
strings:
$string1="pay" nocase
$string2="immediately" nocase
$text_sample="readers" nocase
  
condition:
any of them
}
```

the command I use is `yara yararules.yar testdata` where yararules.yar is the rulesfile and testdata only contains `pay immediately readers`